# Courier New font style in visualforce page that is rendered as pdf

Tags: pdf, fonts, salesforce, visualforce

Some Turkish characters are not displayed in the page when I use Courier New font style.

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
    <table style="font-family : Corier New ; font-size:80%">  
        <tr align="left"><td style="width:40px;"/>
            <td>
                öçşığüÖÇŞİĞÜ
            </td>                     
        </tr>
    </table>
    ...
```

**The output: öçüÖÇÜ**

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
    <table style="font-family : Arial Unicode MS ; font-size:80%">  
        <tr align="left"><td style="width:40px;"/>
            <td>
                öçşığüÖÇŞİĞÜ
            </td>                     
        </tr>
    </table>
    ...
```

**The output: öçşığüÖÇŞİĞÜ**

Please help me

Comment: Most likely Courier New on the machine you use to display the data does not contain those characters. You might want to add other font names to use as fallback.

Comment: Courier New works properly with **<meta charset='ISO-8859-9'>** in a html file but it dosen't work in vf page.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce generates the PDFs server side - doesn't matter what fonts you have installed.

There PDF generator is EXTREMELEY limited.  you can do font-family:courier, but not font-family:courier-new

http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000113353&language=en_US

And this list is misleading - for Arial you have to use Arial Unicode MS, Times-Roman and Helvetic don't work, just use Serif